# UTF8 character encoding, htmlentities and Cross Site Scripting

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, xss, html-entities

I am currently overworking my website and would like to make consequent usage of correct character encoding since I had some with this trouble so far.

My HTML and PHP files are encoded with UTF8, my HTML head looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />.....
```

I use MySQLi and configured my connection like this:

```
$DB->set_charset("utf8");
```

My database is using utf8_general_ci collation.

So I think I set up everything correctly.

Now my problem:
To avoid cross site scripting I everytimes use htmlentities() when displaying data the user has saved into my database in order to break HTML characters like < > " '

```
echo(htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

But when $str contains other special characters like ÄäÖöÜü&ßàé they also get broken and my browser only displays only & Auml; and so on...

Where is my fault? What is the correct method to achieve safety against xss and display utf-8 characters? I think I could need a complete crash course within these topics.
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890004/htmlentities-destroys-german-umlauts-stored-as-utf8) does not match my problem because I already use this parameter.

I would be very thankful if you could help me with this issue.
Best regards
Lukas

Comment: Could it be a locale problem? What if you set the locale for your php process to a UTF8 one if it's not like that already?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! You mean the default_charset setting within my php.ini ? I set it to "UTF-8" but it did not make any effect... I am not really sure if htmlentities is the correct function for me [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)? What means "all applicable characters" ?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue by switching to htmlspecialchars. I think this function does enough for security against xss.

Comment: Be aware that XSS is much more than blacklist based html encoding (as done by `htmlspecialchars()`).